# Best practice to expose and call methods from svelte component

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I built a simple Banner component which is imported in _layout.html. It exposes 5 methods (dismiss, info, warning, ...).

Currently I'm using the store to keep track of these methods as in  _layout.html below.

_layout.html

```
<main>
    <Banner ref:banner/>
    <svelte:component this={child.component} {...child.props} />
</main>

<script>
    export default {
        components: {
            Banner: '../components/Banner.html',
        },

        oncreate() {
            this.store.set({
                Banner: {
                    dismiss: this.refs.banner.dismiss,
                    danger: this.refs.banner.danger,
                    info: this.refs.banner.info,
                    success: this.refs.banner.success,
                    warning: this.refs.banner.warning
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

So I can call them from any part of the app like so:

blog.html

```
...     
  this.store.get().Banner.success('Post saved!')        
} catch (err) {
  this.store.get().Banner.danger(err)
}
...
```

This is working fine however I wonder if this is the best Svelte way to do it.

Comment: I think this question is outdated, ref:xxx seems to be no longer supported in svelte 3:The ref directive is no longer supported — use `bind:this={xxx}, perhaps a tag wih svelte 2 (or whatever this question applies to) should be added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm not sure of a better Svelte way. What you did looks good to me. You could

```
oncreate() {
    Object.assign(this, this.refs.banner);
    //or assign the exposed methods to the root component in any way
}

...
this.root.success('Post saved!');
...
```

Since all elements have reference to the root component.